# Cannot display uploaded images on JSP until 'clean and build' (netbeans)

Tags: image, jsp

I've created a web application on JSP to upload images.

> at J:/PEC_CW/web/uploads/{user_id}/{filemane}

I'm having issues displaying them back from the file system.

When I attempt to display the uploaded image, it does not get loaded (file path is correct). If I check from Windows file system, the image is there. And if I check from the Netbeans project explorer, the image has not been picked up by the project.

Then if I clean and build the project, netbeans picks up the images and consequently images are displayed without any problem.

My question is,

1. What is the solution (surely we cannot re-deploy project every-time a file is uploaded)?
2. Once the project is deployed on the server, does the project continue to keep index of resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deploying a web application to a server consists in creating a war file or an exploded war directory, and deploying this war file or directory. The war file doesn't have any connection whatsoever with the source directory from which it was generated. And, ultimetely, it's deployed on a production server where there is no source directory at all.

If you wan to upload files, configure your webapp to save them in a specific directory on the server's file system, and create a servlet to read the image from this specific directory an stream it to the HTTP response. The war file/exploded war direcory should be considered read-only, for two reasons:

- there's a good chance it actually *is* read-only
- you don't want to have all your uploaded images to be deleted each tim you redeploy the webapp to fix a bug or bring a new feature